# Does a personal VPN created with NEVPNManager affect other apps?

Tags: ios, ios8, vpn, nevpnmanager

I've found a few articles online such as [this one](http://ramezanpour.net/post/2014/08/03/configure-and-manage-vpn-connections-programmatically-in-ios-8/) which discuss using the new NetworkExtension.framework in iOS 8 and it's corresponding NEVPNManager class to create custom VPN configurations programatically.

It's implied that these configurations will only affect my app, and not other things in the background, but I've been unable to find anything definitive. The code references various things with names like `sharedManager` so it's not obvious.

So, if I create a VPN programatically with NEVPNManager and connect to it from within my iOS app, will it affect other apps and/or background services?

Answer (score 1):

We're using NEVPNManager to connect VPN, that limits internet connectivity. All the apps on the device fail to connect their services, when our VPN is connected. However, some system services (like APNS) are still working somehow.

Comment: Also, if you're looking for limiting VPN per app, this can be achieved with MDM Enterprise features, but I think not mixing with NEVPNManager API. iOS 9 looks to provide more API above VPN management.